# How to share custom validators between modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I've built a custom password validator for a template driven form based on this tutorial: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-template-driven-form-validators/#building-a-custom-validator

However, I'd like to use it on multiple forms which are in different parts in the application. I keep getting the error:

```
Type PasswordValidator is part of the declarations of 2 modules: 
SignupModule and AuthModule! Please consider moving PasswordValidator to a higher module that imports SignupModule and AuthModule.
```

If I add the validator to the higher module like it suggests, it doesn't work anymore. The validator is never reached. It seems to need to be imported in the module directly holding the form to be effective.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove `PasswordValidator` from both i.e. `SignupModule and AuthModule` instead add it in root module so that you can use it in entire application

Comment: Or why not created a [SharedModule](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) that exports this validator to any module that imports this SharedModule?

Comment: ^I tried both of those, which is what I meant by "If I add the validator to the higher module like it suggests"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### Issue

This is the error every `Angular` developer get in the beginning. The issue is lack of understanding how Module works in terms of `Declaration` of `Component` and `Directives`

In your case, you a `Directive` and you are trying to use it in two different Modules so you had declare in two different `Modules`. But `Angular` starts complaining that you had declared the same component in more than one `Module`.

Now what developer does, is to move the `Directive` to higher `Module` thinking that it will be available in all its children `Modules` but wait it won't work.

> ### Fix

The actual issue here is the way we think about the Module import. We think if we had the `Directives` or `Component` at the higher level, it will be available in all the its children but not necessarily ( its depends on the execution sequence ).

Just think in other way around. Does my current `Module` import all required `Modules` which contains `Directive` and `Component`. That is the case where we create the `ShareModule` which contains all re-used `Components` and `Directives` and we just import it wherever it requires.

> In short, create a `SharedModule` and declare your common `Directives` and `Components` in it and import this `Module` wherever required.

Please refer this nice official article on shared module - https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: I had previously attempted this method via other stack overflow answers and I couldn't get it to work, however the article you provided showed me that what I was missing before was `exports`. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Sunil! Not to threaten you or anything, but could you elaborate on why you have to reiterate the issue when you could just get straight to the point and to not beat around the bush? Thanks for the very informative answer though! This could help others who are struggling in learning Angular.

Comment: Hi Edric, thanks for asking the this question. There are couple of reason to reiterate your question. [1]. Sometime we answer after looking at their question and eventually they drag the topic to somewhere else. So always ensure that I am answering on the basis of my understanding. [2]. It helps the other people to understand what answer has been given for what query. Note : I am not content writer :)